# SelectBoxIt clashes with CSS file

Tags: jquery, html, css, selectboxit

I'm currently working on a currency converter app & trying to add flag icons to the currencies. I'm using the [SelectBoxIt](http://gregfranko.com/jquery.selectBoxIt.js/) jQuery plugin to do it.

The problem is whenever I use the SelectBoxIt plugin the select options dropdown style clashes, see below.

See how the options collapse horizontally

[image: See how the options collapse horizontally]

Surprisingly if I remove the link to my CSS file the plugin works magically.

Any idea how to solve this?

See full code below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.selectboxit/3.8.0/jquery.selectBoxIt.css" />
</head>
<body onload="convertDineroBottom()">

    <div id="containerSelect"> 
      <select id="from" onchange="convertDineroBottom()" >
        <option value="EUR" data-iconurl="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b7/Flag_of_Europe.svg">EUR</option>
        <option value="USD" data-iconurl="https://cdn.countryflags.com/thumbs/united-states-of-america/flag-400.png">USD</option>
        <option value="GBP" data-iconurl="https://cmkt-image-prd.global.ssl.fastly.net/0.1.0/ps/221487/910/607/m1/fpnw/wm0/united-kingdom-flag-1-.jpg?1414512427&s=f16b2cb24fd704ffcf14b18ee18b5f4e">GBP</option>
        <option value="JPY">JPY</option>
        <option value="HKD">HKD</option>
      </select>

      <select id="to"  onchange="convertDineroTop()">
        <option value="GBP">GBP</option>
        <option value="EUR">EUR</option>
        <option value="USD">USD</option>
        <option value="JPY" selected>JPY</option>
        <option value="HKD">HKD</option>
      </select>
    </div>  

          <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
          <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.selectboxit/3.8.0/jquery.selectBoxIt.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
body{
   background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(100,100,100,1) 0%, rgba(165,165,165,1) 46%, rgba(186,186,190,1) 49%, rgba(205,205,208,1) 50%, rgba(222,218,218,1) 58%, rgba(221,221,221,1) 91%, rgba(181,182,182,1) 100%);
   height: 1080px;
}

nav{
    background-color: turquoise;
}

ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    width: 70%;
    margin: auto;
    padding-top:5%;
}

li{
}

#logo{
}

#date{

}

#containerInput{
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 40%;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top:10%;
}

input{
  border: none;
  height: 160px;
  width: 220px;
  background-color: #0e3d73;
  color: white;
  font-size:2em;
  text-align: center;
}

#arrow{
  margin-top:9%;
}

#arrow img{
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
}

#containerSelect{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  width: 40%;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top:2%;
}

select{
  width: 220px;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```
function convertDineroBottom() {
  var fromCurrency = document.getElementById("from").value;
  var toCurrency = document.getElementById("to").value;


fetch("https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?base=" + fromCurrency)
  .then((resp) => resp.json())
  .then(function(data){
    (fromCurrency===toCurrency) ? 
    document.getElementById("toQuantity").value = document.getElementById("fromQuantity").value :
    document.getElementById("toQuantity").value = data.rates[toCurrency]*document.getElementById("fromQuantity").value;

  })
    .catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
    });
}



function convertDineroTop() {
    var fromCurrency = document.getElementById("from").value;
  var toCurrency = document.getElementById("to").value;


        fetch("https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?base=" + toCurrency)
    .then((resp) => resp.json())
  .then(function(data){
  //if both currencies are the same return identical values
        (toCurrency===fromCurrency) ?
         document.getElementById("fromQuantity").value = document.getElementById("toQuantity").value :
        //otherwise return the top value as the multiplication of top currency rate by the amount specied below
            document.getElementById("fromQuantity").value = data.rates[fromCurrency]*document.getElementById("toQuantity").value;

  })
    .catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
    });
}

$(function() {

              var selectBox = $("select").selectBoxIt();

            });
```

Comment: Hi, please add a [mcve] to the question, otherwise it will be hard to provide any assistance.

Comment: Use your browser dev tools to debug it, you can see exactly where the styling is coming from. It's impossible for anyone to help you without seeing you code

Comment: Added the code guys

Answer (score 0):

Often times css will clash.  Whenever that happens, you have a few options, though they all amount to the same thing: be even more forceful than the bad css.

The best way to do this is to be more specific:

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}

div span {
  background: blue;
}

div > span {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<span></span>

<div>
  <h1><span></span></h1>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

In the example above, `span` is the least specific, `div span` is more specific, and `div > span` is most specific.  Figure out how specific the offending css, and be more specific than it.

Or, use `!important`, but that's really not advised.